# How do I get mouse marker to work on my D3 line chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to follow [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569) of a D3 line chart. But I get an `NaN` message when making the line chart.

Here's my code ([full code here](https://github.com/chrismp/chrismp.github.io/blob/develop/_includes/charts/US-Media-Jobs-timeline.html))

```
    var focus = svg.append('g')
        .attr('class','focus')
        .style('display','none');

    focus.append('circle')
        .attr('r',4.5)
        .attr('fill','none')
        .attr('stroke','steelblue');

    focus.append('text')
        .attr('x',9)
        .attr('dy','.35em');

    svg.append('rect')
        .attr('class','overlay')
        .attr('fill','none')
        .attr('pointer-events','all')
        .attr('width',width)
        .attr('height',height)
        .on('mouseover',function(){
            focus.style('display',null);
        })
        .on('mouseout',function(){
            focus.style('display','none');
        })
        .on('mouseout',function(){
            console.log(x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]));
            var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
            i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
            d0 = data[i-1],
            d1 = data[i],
            d = (x0-d0.date) > (d1.date-d0) ? d1 : d0;
            focus.attr('transform','translate('+x(d.date)+','+y(d.close)+')');
            focus.select('text').text(d.values);
        });
});
```

When I run the code and mouseover a line, I get this message in my console

```
Unexpected value translate(NaN,NaN) parsing transform attribute.
this.setAttribute(name, value);
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: can you provide a subset of your csv data...may be then i ll be able to recreate it in a fiddle

Comment: @Cyril Here's a Pastebin http://pastebin.com/Qp5ynUhW

Comment: Ok your code has issues because
           _focus.attr('transform','translate('+x(d.date)+','+y(d.close)+')');_
in your data set there is no _d.date_ or _d.close_, as a result you are getting NAN for the translate..I think you just copied the example here but, you need to understand that the example dataset and your dataset are completely different. So copy paste may be fail :) I would suggest you to understand the example and then implement it.